# module.exports & outside scope

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

foo.coffee:

```
class Foo
  constructor: ->
    console.log BAR

module.exports = Foo
```

main.coffee:

```
BAR = 1

class Bar
  constructor: ->
    console.log BAR

new Bar()

Foo = require './foo'
new Foo()
```

then

```
$ coffee main.coffee 
1
ReferenceError: BAR is not defined
```

Why `BAR` isn't accessible inside the instance of `Foo`?
Can I make it 'visible' to `Foo` objects (besides of explicitly passing it to a constructor)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that in CoffeeScript when you declare a variable it is always compiled to a local variable.

Therefore, in your declaration above, when you do `BAR=1` that gets compiled to `var BAR=1`. So, the variable is always scoped locally and it means it is not accessible to other modules.

So, the solution that Jed Schneider gave you is the correct one, with just one caveat, in Node.js, when you are in a module, the `this` reference points to the `module.exports` object and not to the `global` object as Jed seemed to suggest (this is a source of confusion between node.js and the browser, since in the browser it does behave as Jed explained).

So, this is always true

```
//module.js
console.log(this==module.exports) //yield true
```

Whereas within a function, the `this` keyword would point to the global object. So, this is also true:

```
//module.js
(function(){
   console.log(this==global); //yields true
})()
```

Being this the case, to solve your problem, you can use Jed Schneider approach, but make sure to wrap your code inside an [IIFE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) so that your `this` points to `global` and not to `module.exports`.

So, this produces your expected results:

```
do ->
   @BAR = 1

   class Bar
      constructor: ->
         console.log BAR

   new Bar()
   Foo = require './foo'
   new Foo()
```

This produces the output

```
1
1
```

Comment: excellent explanation. I was unaware that I was actually attaching to the `module.exports` object in node (less my specialty) but that clearly makes sense. +1 for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Bar
   constructor: ->
     console.log @BAR
```

and then setting

```
@BAR = 1
```

should do what you expect. this is shorthand for `this.` which will place it on the global object, as you would expect constants to be defined. personally, I'd make a constants namespace and export that, the same as you do `Foo`.

Comment: The problem is not with Bar class but with Foo. And it I write @BAR=1 in main.coffee & @BAR in foo.coffee, it prints 'undefined'.